# Java Httpconnection preprocess url content for jsoup or other parser

Tags: java, parsing, web-crawler, jsoup, httpconnection

I have a program, which connects to an Url with Java HttpConnection. The inputstream is parsed by jsoup. My Problem is that this is taking about 1 second for each Url. The webpage has about 12000 lines of code, but I just need a specific area (about 500 lines within a div), so I am wondering if I could preprocess the inputstream and just handing over this part of code to jsoup for parsing. As I have about 100.000 pages to crawl I cannot handle it within one day with one server. I hope that a kind of preprocessing can lower the parsing time to sth. like 50-150 ms. I allready checked that jsoup parsing is the bottleneck and not the internet connection / downloading.

I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: Which version of jsoup are you using?

Comment: Try upgrading to the latest version: 1.8.2

Comment: Hey Luiggi, unfortunatly this just get a benifit of about 20ms by parsing ... so I came down from 1000ms to 980 ms :) I will try the other solutions. As I have a result I will post it here. For any further hints I am happy

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course your solution is on the right track.

But the problem is - where does your block of code in the `InputStream` start?
This depends only on the HTML document code.

If it's quite specific you can read from stream and throw away the bytes that are not matched as start of the block.

You can read all the input stream and use `indexOf` or some `RegExp` pattern (regex is much more slower).

Then prepend `<html><body>` and append `</body></html>` to the extracted `String` and here you have it for the `JSoup` to parse

Comment: Oh that's good to know, that RegExp is much slower than indexOf, this saves me time. Ok for indexOf I can imagine, that I try to find the startindex AND the endindex of the div, right? So I have to use two times indexOf to get one specific block. But for reading the stream directly and throwing away the non needed bytes I only know that I can do that when I know which byte is the start and end byte. But I dont know how to stream the bytes until a specific String (in this case a html ID) passes ... Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

I think for your use case JSoup may be the wrong tool. You may look into SAX based XML/HTML parser libraries fro Java.

The good implementations should be as fast as a "brutal" string search for your opening tag with the benefit of allowing you stay in the realm of HTML syntax.

It all depends, if the HTML you need to process is always incuded in the  same (literally) tag, the approach from @Xeon might be a tick faster. If the tags are changing a bit, you might find better results witha SAX based parser.

Here are some:

- [TagSoup](http://hotsax.sourceforge.net/)
- [HotSax](http://hotsax.sourceforge.net/)